# bigquery for time series data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this. The row includes a timestamp and count as measurement of a value at that time.

```
Row timestamp count
1 2018-08-20 04:01:39.108497 31
2 2018-08-20 04:01:45.109497 45
3 2018-08-20 04:01:49.109497 44
4 2018-08-20 04:02:39.102497 33
5 2018-08-20 04:02:45.101497 41
6 2018-08-20 04:02:49.103497 22
7 2018-08-20 04:03:39.102497 23
8 2018-08-20 04:03:45.102497 42
9 2018-08-20 04:03:49.103497 41
```

I would like to aggregate this into this as a minute level aggregation as avg(count)

```
Row timestamp count
1 2018-08-20 04:01:00 40
2 2018-08-20 04:02:00 32
3 2018-08-20 04:03:00 35
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: can u explain one row of your dataset, For example, in the first row, what does `04:01:39.108497` signify ?

Comment: The count `42` seems to be associated with minute `04:03:00`, not `04:02:00`.  Can you explain why you have `42` associated with minute `04:02:00` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE) dt, CAST(AVG(cnt) AS INT64) viewCount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY dt
```

If to apply to dummy data in  your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-08-20 04:01:39.108497' ts, 31 cnt UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:01:45.109497', 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:01:49.109497', 44 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:02:39.102497', 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:02:45.101497', 41 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:02:49.103497', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:03:39.102497', 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:03:45.102497', 42 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-08-20 04:03:49.103497', 41 
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE) dt, CAST(AVG(cnt) AS INT64) viewCount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY dt
-- ORDER BY dt
```

result is

```
Row dt                      viewCount
1   2018-08-20 04:01:00 UTC 40   
2   2018-08-20 04:02:00 UTC 32   
3   2018-08-20 04:03:00 UTC 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC()`:

```
select timestamp_trunc(minute, timestamp) as timestamp_min,
       sum(count)  -- or whatever aggregation you want
from t
group by timestamp_min;
```

Your question is unclear on what aggregation you want.  For instance, "35" doesn't appear in the data.